# Loop and output 4 rows of posts on home page

Tags: posts, loop

I've found some information about how to loop through posts but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

Basically I'm looking to output 4 rows of posts (max of 10 post) on my home page.

First row:

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile large"></div>
</div>
```

Second row:

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Third row:

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile large"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Fourth row:

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a wire frame showing the desired layout.
[image]

Comment: Here ya go: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Lets see on your structure. You have 2 block, and each block have 2 lines. First line of block have 2 posts, second line - 3 posts.
See [screen](http://joxi.ru/eAO97lRu45eb8m)

First we chunk array to 5 per each chunk;
Next step wee need separate each array with 5 posts to 2 and 3 posts.

Than print all of this and add special class for every second block.

All code will looks like

```
global $wp_query;
$posts      = $wp_query->posts; // get posts from global query for home page
$chunks     = [];
$i          = 0;
$five_elems = array_chunk( $posts, 5 ); // Split an array into chunks 5 per array

foreach ( $five_elems as $five ) {
    $lines = array_chunk( $five, 2 ); // split our chunked array (5 per array) to 2-2-1
    $res   = array_merge( $lines[1], $lines[2] ); // merge 2-1 to 3 elements
    unset( $lines[1] ); // delete second `2`
    unset( $lines[2] ); // delete last `1`
    $lines[1] = $res; // create chunked array with 2-3 elems

    /*
     * Save all data to this like:
     *
 array (size=2)
  0 =>
    array (size=2)
      0 =>
        array (size=2)
          0 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1286]
              ...
          1 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1287]
              ...
      1 =>
        array (size=3)
          0 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1288]
              ...
          1 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1289]
              ...
          2 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1290]
              ...
  1 =>
    array (size=2)
      0 =>
        array (size=2)
          0 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1291]
              ...
          1 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1292]
              ...
      1 =>
        array (size=3)
          0 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1293]
              ...
          1 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1294]
              ...
          2 =>
            object(WP_Post)[1421]
              ...

 */
    $chunks[] = $lines;
}

foreach ( $chunks as $posts ) {
    ++ $i;

    // create class for every second element and other
    $class = $i % 2 === 0 ? 'small-right' : 'small-left';

    // your line with 2 posts (small and large)
    echo '<div class="tiles ' . $class . '">';
    foreach ( $posts[0] as $block ) {
        echo '<div class="tile">' . $block->ID . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';


    // your 3 per line posts
    echo '<div class="tiles">';
    foreach ( $posts[1] as $block ) {
        echo '<div class="tile">' . $block->ID . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Insert this code inside your `home.php` instead `while(have_posts())..`loop.

And remember - this is a simple example. I think it`s not best solution. I hope this code will help you and you understood me.

Comment: I get your concept for sectioning the content into 2 blocks of 5 post each but I'm confused by your code. When I add this to the page as you suggest I don't get any output.

Comment: Where do you added this code?

Comment: I'm using the blankslate theme and I added this to page.php. 
I replaced `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

Comment: This will work only in home.php.

Comment: I dont have a home.php file

Comment: You says wanna place posts on home page. home.php this is file for posts page. See dashboard > settings > reading

Comment: I'm using a custom file 'front-page.php' which is basically code taken from the page.php file.

Comment: So, it’s does not matter. You can set in $posts your array with posts and use anywhere. You can get posts using get_posts function and use my code

Comment: Could this code be used in the functions.php file?

Comment: No. You can do WP_Query and pass found posts in my $posts variable.

Comment: Sorry, im fairly new to wordpress dev. How would I use get_post with your code?